# Does %* in batch file mean all command line arguments?

Tags: windows, batch, script, command-line, wildcards

Does `%*` in batch file mean all command line arguments?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Yes.  According to the [official Microsoft documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150321150557/https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true):

> The %* batch parameter is a wildcard reference to all the arguments, not including %0, that are passed to the batch file.

Comment: note: if you have 30 words separated with spaces as argument, you can only take the 9 first words with %i, with i from 1 to 9, but with %* you can take all the 30 words

Comment: @kokbira or you can use [shift](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/shift.mspx?mfr=true) to access the rest

Comment: @TWiStErRob - I'm sure you know it but to be clear... even with %* you need to use [shift](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/shift.mspx?mfr=true) to access parameters beyond %9. The advantage of using %* is you can pass the entire ORIGINAL parameter list (including parameters that have been "shifted out") to an external batch or other program, or with a `call :label %*`, even if you don't know how many parameters are in the list (or if it's more than 9).

Comment: Is this quoted properly, like `"$@"` in sh?

Answer (score 2):

Besides this, a comment by @kobkira notes that you can take only up to 9 arguments in conventional syntax. Like this if you want to get n number of arguments in separate array style variables, use this syntax:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & set "n=30"
for /l %%a in (1,1,%n%) do (
  for /f "tokens=%%a delims= " %%b in ('echo %*') do (
    set "arg[%%~a]=%%~b"
  )
)
```

Comment: Does *array style*  mean you include indices into variable names? Batch file doesn't support private variables, every assignment exposes variable as environment var... ((